How do I prevent ExPex preamble from becoming an orphan?
I'm wondering how to prevent orphan lines in ExPex examples. I'm using the package lua-widow-control to eliminate orphans from my book, but this doesn't seem to affect multipart ExPex examples with a preamble, where the preamble to the example is stranded on the previous page as an orphan:

I would like to automatically force a page break whenever this happens. What I don't want is to remove all page breaking from ExPex examples. I would still like to allow page breaks between parts in an ExPex example, such as in the following:

Is there any way to do this automatically? I'm not opposed to doing it manually as it doesn't show up that much in the document, but it would be nice to not have to rely on manually checking them as there are hundreds of examples in the thesis.

Can you please show an example of code? It's not necessary that it produces the orphan line, that can be added quite easily.

Off-topic but is "altneration" in example 6.21 correctly spelled?
